# Require a Password to close an HTA

Tags: vbscript, passwords, hta, locked

I was hoping someone would be able to proved me some direction. I would like to set an application launcher I have created to require a password to be closed. Thank you for any assistance you are able to offer.
But here is some incomplete code to show you my purpose.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
dim password
password=InputBox("Please Enter Password:","3 - Tries Left")
if password = ("9999") then 
    dim correct correct =MsgBox("Correct Password!",64,"correct")
    objShell.Run("shutdown /m shutdown -r -f -t 0")
Else 
    dim again
    again =MsgBox("Incorrect Password! Do You Want To Try Again?",53,"Incorrect Password!")
    If again = 4 Then
        dim password2
        password2=InputBox("Please Enter Password:","2 - Tries Left")
        if password2 = ("9999") then
            dim correct2 
            correct2 =MsgBox("Correct Password!",64,"correct")
```

Sorry ! I was unable to post all of the code.I just need to know what to put to close the existing window. I think telling it to close MSHTA.EXE will work.

Comment: I suspect it isn't possible. Look into something like kiosk mode: http://www.howtogeek.com/173562/how-to-easily-put-a-windows-pc-into-kiosk-mode-with-assigned-access/

Comment: Pretty sure there is a way. I've already locked the HTA into full screen, removed right click close, as well as close and minimize, and ALT F4 close. So now I just need to script a button that will require a password before exiting the HTA.

Comment: @BaTan How about the Task Manager? Have you scripted it out too?

Comment: Nope it's been disabled via group policy.

Comment: Did you mean something in that direction ? ==> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55WfJb-0UTc

Comment: Can you show us what did you tried so far as code ?

Comment: Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
dim password
password=InputBox("Please Enter Password:","3 - Tries Left")
if password = ("9999") then
 dim correct
 correct =MsgBox("Correct Password!",64,"correct")
 objShell.Run("shutdown /m shutdown -r -f -t 0")
Else
 dim again
 again =MsgBox("Incorrect Password! Do You Want To Try Again?",53,"Incorrect Password!")
 If again = 4 Then
 dim password2
 password2=InputBox("Please Enter Password:","2 - Tries Left")
 if password2 = ("9999") then
  dim correct2
  correct2 =MsgBox("Correct Password!",64,"correct")

Comment: I was unable to post all of the code. However this works! I just need to know what to put to close the existing window. I think telling it to close MSHTA.EXE will work.

Comment: Check my answer below in HTA ! and hope that what did you look for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTA and i hope that can did the trick.

**NB :** The Password is **9999** and of course you can change it at this line
`MyGoodPassword = "9999"`

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="Access to the system © Hackoo © 2015"
BORDER="THIN"
BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL"
ICON="Explorer.exe"
INNERBORDER="NO"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
SCROLL="NO"
SELECTION="NO"
SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
</HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
<BODY TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1"><CENTER><DIV><SPAN ID="ONSCR"></SPAN></DIV></CENTER></BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Option Explicit
Dim Title,ws,Voice,ErrorMsg,WelcomeMsg,MyGoodPassword,Password,Temp,Tests,ProcessEnv,UserName
Title = "Access to the system © Hackoo 2015"
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set ProcessEnv = Ws.Environment("Process")
UserName = ProcessEnv("USERNAME")
Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Tests = Temp &"\Tests.txt"
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub window_onload()
    CenterWindow 280,180
    Call PasswordForm()
    Call TextFocus
    Dim Count : Count = 0
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(Tests) Then
        Dim Logfile : Set Logfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Tests,2,True)
        Logfile.writeline Count
        Logfile.Close
    end If
   Call Kill("Explorer.exe")
   Call DisableTaskMgr()
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub PasswordForm()
    Self.document.title = "Access to the system © Hackoo 2015"
    Self.document.bgColor = "DarkOrange"
    ONSCR.InnerHTML="<center><FONT COLOR=""#FFFFFF"" SIZE=""+1"" FACE=""VERDANA,ARIAL,HELVETICA,SANS-SERIF"">Type your Password</FONT><br><br><input type=""password"" name=""PasswordArea"" size=""20"" onKeyUp=""TextFocus""><P>"_
    &"<input  type=""Submit"" STYLE=""HEIGHT:25;WIDTH:190"" value=""Access to the system"" name=""run_button""  onClick=""CheckPassword"">"
END Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub CheckPassword
    Dim NB_Tests_MAX : NB_Tests_MAX = 3
    Dim Readfile,Count,NB_Tests_Remaining,Logfile,Controle,Command,Executer,MsgNumbTests,MsgReboot
    Set Voice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
    ErrorMsg = "ATTENTION ! ! ! "& vbcr &"The Password is Wrong ! "& vbcr &"Try Again !"
    WelcomeMsg = "Welcome again "& DblQuote(UserName) &" in your System !"
    MyGoodPassword = "9999"
    Set Readfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Tests,1)
    Count = Readfile.ReadAll
    Readfile.Close
    Controle = True
    While Controle
        Count = Count + 1
        NB_Tests_Remaining = NB_Tests_MAX - Count
        Set Logfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Tests,2,True)
        Logfile.writeline Count
        Logfile.Close
        If PasswordArea.Value <> MyGoodPassword Then
            Voice.Speak ErrorMsg
            ws.Popup ErrorMsg,"1",Title,0+16
            MsgNumbTests =  "ATTENTION !!! "&vbcr&"Bad Password and NB°of TESTS is " & Count &"."&vbCr&_
            "The remaining number of tests is "& NB_Tests_Remaining
            Voice.Speak MsgNumbTests
            MsgBox MsgNumbTests,48,Title
            Sleep(1)
            Location.Reload(True)
        end if
        If PasswordArea.Value = MyGoodPassword Then
            If objFSO.FileExists(Tests) Then objFSO.DeleteFile Tests,True
            Controle = False
            Voice.Speak WelcomeMsg
            ws.Popup WelcomeMsg,"1",Title,0+64
            Call Launch("Explorer.exe")
            Call EnableTaskMgr()
            Self.Close
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Count = NB_Tests_MAX Then
            If objFSO.FileExists(Tests) Then objFSO.DeleteFile Tests,True
            Voice.Speak "The computer will reboot in 30 seconds !"
            MsgReboot = "The Limit number of tests is reached ! "&vbcr& "The computer will Reboot in 30 seconds !"
                       MsgBox MsgReboot,48,"The Limit number of tests is reached ! "
                       Command="cmd /c Shutdown.exe -r -t 30 -c " & chr(34) & "The computer will reboot in 30 seconds !" & chr(34)
                       Executer = WS.Run(Command,0,False)
                       window.close
        End If
            Exit Sub
        wend
    End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sub TextFocus
        PasswordArea.Focus
    End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sub Kill(Process)
        Dim Ws,Command,Execution
        Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
        Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
    End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sub Launch(Process)
        Dim Ws,Command,Execution
        Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        Command = "cmd /c Start "&Process&""
        Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
    End Sub
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'------------------------------EnableTaskMgr----------------------------------------
    Sub EnableTaskMgr()
        Dim WshShell,System
        System="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\"
        Set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Wshshell.RegWrite System, "REG_SZ"
        WshShell.RegWrite System &"\DisableTaskMgr", 0, "REG_DWORD"
    End sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-----------------------------DisableTaskMgr-----------------------------------------
    Sub DisableTaskMgr()
        Dim WshShell,System
        System="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\"
        Set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Wshshell.RegWrite System, "REG_SZ"
        WshShell.RegWrite System &"\DisableTaskMgr", 1, "REG_DWORD"
    End sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sub Sleep(intNumSecs)
' Because WScript.Sleep () is not available in HTA
' scripts, invoke a VBScript file to do the waiting.
        Dim strScriptFile, strCommand, intRetcode, objWS
        If intNumSecs <= 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set objWS = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
        strScriptFile = "%temp%\wait" & intNumSecs & "seconds.vbs"
        strCommand = "cmd /c ""echo WScript.Sleep " & intNumSecs * 1000 & " >" & strScriptFile & _
        "&start /wait """" wscript.exe " & strScriptFile & """"
        intRetCode = objWS.Run (strCommand, 0, True)
        If intRetCode = 0 Then Exit Sub
    End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Function DblQuote(Str)
             DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
    End Function
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</SCRIPT>
```